# How many bits are required to store MARIE's instruction set?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, machine-code, marie

I know that MARIE's instruction set has 16-bit per instruction, given that there are 9 instructions, doesn't it make sense that 16*9 = 144bits are needed to store all of the instruction? But apparently its wrong, whats wrong with my reasoning and can you guide me to the answer?

Comment: 9 instructions require `ceil(log2(9))` = 4 bits. The other 12 bits are probably used for operands.

Comment: That's generally not what that phrasing means.  I assume they're asking how wide a *single* instruction needs to be (since they're fixed-width), not to store one copy of each instruction.  It's a weird question because using fewer bits would leave less room for memory addresses or branch displacements.

Comment: V=2^N, and, N=log2(V), where V is the number of different values that can be represented in N number of bits, and, 2 is for binary.  So, 16=2^4, meaning 16 different values can be represented by 4 bits in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following data structure

```
-------------------------------------
| Opcode  | Address                 |
-------------------------------------
| _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |
-------------------------------------
  Bit Bit   Bit                 Bit
   15  12    11                   0
```

as [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) and [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) already mentioned in his comments.